# How do I check if all files inside directories are valid jpegs (Linux, sh script needed)?

Tags: shell, image-processing

Ok, I got a directory (for instance, named '/photos') in which there are different directories 
(like '/photos/wedding', '/photos/birthday', '/photos/graduation', etc...) which have .jpg files in them. Unfortunately, some of jpeg files are broken. I need to find a way how to determine, which files are broken.
I found out, that there is tool named imagemagic, which can help a lot. If you use it like this:

```
identify -format '%f' whatever.jpg
```

it prints the name of the file  only if file is valid, if it is not it prints something like "identify: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x69 0x75 `whatever.jpg' @ jpeg.c/EmitMessage/232.".
So the correct solution should be find all files ending with ".jpg", apply to them "identify", and if the result is just the name of the file - don't do anything, and if the result is different from the name of the file - then save the name of the file somethere (like in a file "errors.txt").

Any ideas how I can probably do that?

Comment: Related: [Is there a tool to check the file integrity of a series of images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46919)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put this into bash script file or run directly:

`find -name "*.jpg" -type f |xargs --no-run-if-empty identify -format '%f' 1>ok.txt 2>errors.txt`

In case `identify` is missing, here is how to install it in Ubuntu:
  sudo apt install imagemagick --no-install-recommends

Comment: Can also be written as `find -name '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%f" {} \; 1>ok.txt 2>errors.txt`.

Comment: Mark it as accepted, however, the final script is:

    find -name '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%f\n" {} \; 2>errors.txt

That might be exactly what I need, tested on test data and errors.txt give me all necessary info (ok.txt makes no good to me, so I deleted it from the script).
Thanks all who participated!

Comment: The command given in the answer gives me an error

    xargs: identify: No such file or directory

Comment: @Graf thanks for noting that.    London guy: Check first if identify is installed.

Comment: @alexx-roche answer below is more relevant (detect partial jpegs)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for files with space characters in their filenames.

Answer (score 17):

The short-short version:

`find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec jpeginfo -c {} \; | grep -E "WARNING|ERROR"`

You might not need the same find options, but jpeginfo was the solution that worked for me:

`find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg"| xargs jpeginfo -c | grep -E "WARNING|ERROR" | cut -d " " -f 1`

as a script (as requested in this question)

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f \
\( -iname "*.jpg" \
 -o -iname "*.jpeg" \) \
-exec jpeginfo -c {} \; | \
grep -E "WARNING|ERROR" | \
cut -d " " -f 1
```

I was clued into jpeginfo for this by http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2352/find-corrupted-jpeg-image-files and this explained [mixing find -o OR with -exec](http://linuxaria.com/howto/linux-shell-how-to-use-the-exec-option-in-find-with-examples?lang=en#comment-4035)

Comment: find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec identify -format '%f' {} \; 1>/dev/null # is faster then jpeginfo

Comment: Unfortunately `identify` does not complain about some truncated jpg files I have, but `jpeginfo -c` does, so I recommend `jpeginfo -c`

Answer (score 15):

One problem with `identify -format` is that it doesn't actually verify that the file is not corrupt, it just makes sure that it's really a jpeg.

To actually test it you need something to convert it.  But the convert that comes with *ImageMagick* seems to silently ignore non-fatal errors in the jpeg (such as being truncated.)

One thing that works is this:

```
djpeg -fast -grayscale -onepass file.jpg > /dev/null
```

If it returns an error code, the file has a problem. If not, it's good.

There are other programs that could be used as well.

Comment: That was important to remark. Alexx's answer shows another tool to check a JPG file: `jpeginfo -c file`.

Comment: Just in case, if you need to check all jpg files in folder do this -- `for f in *.jpg; do djpeg -fast -grayscale -onepass $f > /dev/null;  done`

Answer (score 2):

This script will print out the names of the bad files:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /photos -name '*.jpg' | while read FILE; do
    if [[ $(identify -format '%f' "$FILE" 2>/dev/null) != $FILE ]]; then
        echo "$FILE"
    fi
done
```

You could run it as is or as `./badjpegs > errors.txt` to save the output to a file.

To break it down, the `find` command finds `*.jpg` files in `/photos` or any of its subdirectories. These file names are piped to a while loop, which reads them in one at a time into the variable `$FILE`. Inside the loop, we grab the output of `identify` using the `$(...)` operator and check if it matches the file name. If not, the file is bad and we print the file name.

It may be possible to simplify this. Most UNIX commands indicate success or failure in their exit code. If the `identify` command does this, then you could simplify the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /photos -name '*.jpg' | while read FILE; do
    if ! identify "$FILE" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "$FILE"
    fi  
done
```

Here the condition is simplified to `if ! identify; then` which means, "did identify fail?"